# How can I round a float number to fixed decimal parts using python

Tags: python

I have some prices like 5.35, 10.91, 15.55, which I round with two decimals using

```
Price = "{:.2f}".format(Price)
```

But how can I make them to be round **based on fixed decimals 0.50 and 0.90** and have

5.50, 10.90, 15.50

Thank you

Comment: Do you want every number to have the decimals rounded to the closest value between .50 and .90? So .35 becomes .50 and .82 becomes .90?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: You need some custom rounding function as this 0.5, 0.9 is not standard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have float number with the fractional part you can use first and second example else with all number (in fact all other type) you can use third and fourth.
Num is your fractional part. x is yout 0.5 and y your 0.9

```
def round(num, x, y) :
    av = (x+y)/2
    if num < av :
        return x
    return y
```

Or if you want pass numer like 15.98:

```
def round(num, x, y) :
    av = (x+y)/2
    if num % 1 < av :
        return int(num)+x
    return int(num)+y
```

You can than call:

```
round(15.98,0.5,0.9)
```

> Output: 15.9

Or something like:

```
def round(number):
    x=0.5
    y=0.9
    if type(number) is float: 
        av = (x+y)/2
        if number % 1 < av :
            return int(number)+x
        return int(number)+y
    return number
```

All of this is rounding down. If you would like round up the construction will be:

```
def round(number):
    x=0.5
    y=0.9
    if type(number) is float: 
        av = (x+y)/2
        from builtins import round as rd
        if rd(number % 1,2 ) < av :
            return int (number)+x
         return int (number)+y
     return number
```

Comment: Thank you Elcon :)

Comment: Doing it this way 5 rounds to 5.5 instead of 4.9. It may or may not be the expected result though.

Comment: Especially the last two example

Comment: @Hirabayashi extra profit ;) BUT ElConrado left out the equality if result is already on .50 or .90

Answer (score 0):

This function should do the trick for the examples that you provided:

```
def fixed_round(number):
    decimal = number - int(number)
    if (abs(0.5 - decimal)) < (abs(0.9 - decimal)):
        return int(number) + 0.50
    else:
        return int(number) + 0.90
```

If you want it to round to full numbers, in the case where the decimals are closer to the integer than to 0.5, you will need to adjust for that ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
import math


def weird_round(x):
    if round(x % 1, 1) >= 0.9:
        return math.floor(x) + 0.9
    return math.floor(x) + 0.5


prices = [5.35, 10.91, 15.55]

for price in prices:
    text = "{:.2f}".format(weird_round(price))
    print(price, '->', text)

5.35 -> 5.50
10.91 -> 10.90
15.55 -> 15.50
```

Comment: @glibdud now it does.